# what payment gateways can i use in moodle in Pakistan?

Tags: moodle

I am recently working in moodle 3.0 and developing an e-learning system for my university but i am stuck with the payment gateways. As Paypal is not working in pakistan so what is an alternative of it...

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this [plugin](https://moodle.org/plugins/enrol_authorizedotnet). If this doesn't works for you then you will have to go for custom plugins that are either paid or they can be made through developers.